# Best Free alternative to WHM/Cpanel

Tags: linux, cpanel, whm

Few days ago I purchased a cheap VPS for a project. Our budget is very small so i can't afford to buy WHM and Cpanel. Are there any free hosting control panels that offer same amount of functionality?

This VPS is just a blank cent os so every thing has to be installed by me. I am a very new to managing a server and am struggling very much I am a web developer. I Hope someone can offer advice.

The application I want to host is made using PHP, MySql

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Webmin (http://www.webmin.com/)

Basically cpanel but better.